# How to log signals to an application signals with a log handler?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals, signal-handling

There are ways to do some work with linux `signal handlers`.

1. We can either register system handlers for every signals (if we have sourcecode) or
2. Run the process under `strace` to view them.

*Stratergy 1:*
But if we dont have *source code*, how can we catch a `signals` to an application to do something with it and return back? (not a one time debugging but permanent feature). [may be hack a `system call`?]

*Stratergy 2:*
And in case we do have *source code*, is writing to a file safe in case of multiple signals ? or is it more safe to execute signal handler in a `fork()` process and discard `SIGCHLD`? what happens if another signals comes in when handling previous signal?

Answer (score 2):

For your *Stratergy 2*, depends on how your log files are written and how the signals are triggered (asynchronously or not). Normally *stdio* library functions are not async-signal-safe.

See details in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

> ```
>    To avoid problems with unsafe functions, there are two possible
>    choices:
>
>    1. Ensure that (a) the signal handler calls only async-signal-safe
>       functions, and (b) the signal handler itself is reentrant with
>       respect to global variables in the main program.
>
>    2. Block signal delivery in the main program when calling functions
>       that are unsafe or operating on global data that is also accessed
>       by the signal handler.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> Stratergy 1: But if we dont have source code, how can we catch a signals to an application to do something with it and return back? (not a one time debugging but permanent feature). [may be hack a system call?]

To intercept a signal delivered to a process there are at least 2 ways:

- [`ptrace(2)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1935641) (which is what `strace` uses) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1935641) for an example.
- [`LD_PRELOAD`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html#ENVIRONMENT): (I'd not advise this approach) you can use it to set handlers for every signal and replace `signal` and `sigaction` with two wrapper functions to prevent the program from overriding your signal handlers (please note the recommendations in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51256421/1833711)).